# Droid Charts Android Java Issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout, charts, jfreechart

I am following this android droid charts tutorial ...

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/creating-charts-with-droidcharts-for-android/

At one point he does this

> setContentView(new
>   XYLineChart(getApplicationContext()));

I want to specify an xml layout and then add this view to it ... How can I do that ?  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an xml file 'linearlayoutgraph'.

Then use the following code to call setContentView using this layout, while also adding other Views/Graph to it:

```
public class Graph extends Activity{

    LinearLayout linearlayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            linearlayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.linearlayoutgraph, null);
            ContentValues datasetDescription = new ContentValues();
            //add your graph
            xyLineChart mView = new xyLineChart(this, datasetDescription, createDataset());
            linearlayout.addView(mView);
            setContentView(linearlayout);
    }

//create data
private XYDataset createDataset()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it, because in that they extend view in that class so it will catch whole window.

If you want to do this than try this: take linearlayout in XML and than take add this view in it dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "they extend view" . Isn't that what a custom control should do ?